# Laravel How Make DB raw can inside funtion

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have problem on laravel. I want to showing percentage on with eloquent, but return null value

This Is My Controller

```
  $group_categories = Proyek::with(['modul' => function($query){
        $query->select(DB::raw('((select count(*) from modul where status = 0 and deleted_at IS NULL) / 
                      (select count(*) from modul where deleted_at IS NULL)) * 
                        100 as count' ));
    }])->get();
```

This Is Json return

```
{
id: "10",
proyek: "JuZka",
created_at: "2018-08-12 01:54:04",
updated_at: "2018-09-23 05:49:13",
modul: [ ]
},
```

Comment: Do you want to count the `modul` rows that belong to the `proyek`? How is the `modul` relationship defined?

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like this:

```
$all_models = (new Proyek)->count();
$models = (new Proyek)->where('status', 0)->count();
$percentage = $models / $all_models * 100;
$group_categories = Proyek::wheere('modul', $percentage);
```